# Edit C# Class Using MsBuild

Tags: msbuild

Can I edit my C# classes by using MSBuild? 
I want to build my project in two steps.

1. First I want to edit my C# class.
2. Second I want to build the project.

Is it possible?

Comment: I would look in to [T4 templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd820620.aspx), in particular [this blog post](http://www.olegsych.com/2010/04/understanding-t4-msbuild-integration/#ConfiguringProject) referenced by [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21820309) might be exactly what you're looking for