# T4 templates not transformed during build

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, templates, t4

#### What I have done

I have tried to compile my T4 templates into a c# file.

What I have tried from **[Microsoft: Invoke text transformation in the build process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/code-generation-in-a-build-process?view=vs-2019)**

By adding in my .csproj file:

```xml
  <Import Project="TextTemplating\Microsoft.TextTemplating.targets" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TransformOnBuild>true</TransformOnBuild>
    <OverwriteReadOnlyOutputFiles>true</OverwriteReadOnlyOutputFiles>
    <TransformOutOfDateOnly>false</TransformOutOfDateOnly>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <T4ParameterValues Include="ProjectDir">
      <Value>$(ProjectDir)</Value>
      <Visible>false</Visible>
    </T4ParameterValues>
  </ItemGroup>
```

`TextTemplating` is a directory containing the TextTemplating files from my editor located at:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\msbuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\TextTemplating

#### The templates

The base template (**named ModelTemplate.tt**):

```cs
<#@ template language="C#" #>
<#@ parameter name="ClassName" type="System.String"#>
<#@ parameter name="Namespace" type="System.String"#>

namespace <#= Namespace #> 
{
    public class <#= ClassName #>
    {

    }
}
```

And finally the template for testing the **ModelTemplate.tt** (named ModelTemplateTest.tt):

```cs
<#@ template debug="false" language="C#" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>
<#
    _ClassNameField = "Model";
    _NamespaceField = "MyNamespace";
#>
<#@ include file="$(ProjectDir)\Templates\ModelTemplate.tt"#>
```

#### Output from the build

```
A custom tool 'TextTemplatingFilePreprocessor' is associated with file 'Templates\ModelTemplate.tt', but the output of the custom tool was not found in the project.  You may try re-running the custom tool by right-clicking on the file in the Solution Explorer and choosing Run Custom Tool.
```

**BUT** the ModelTemplateTest.tt is compiled into:

```cs
namespace MyNamespace 
{
    public class Model
    {

    }
}
```

How I can call `TextTemplatingFilePreprocessor` in my build?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution **(with Visual Studio Enterprise 2019)** was to import `$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TextTemplating\Microsoft.TextTemplating.targets` in the `.csproj` file as follows:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TransformOnBuild>true</TransformOnBuild>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TextTemplating\Microsoft.TextTemplating.targets" />
</Project>
```

Related StackOverflow thread: [Product of build-time T4 transformation is used only in the next build](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21820309/7047493)

Comment: Do you have a way to not specify explictly the "v16.0"?
This would require dynamic values based on the build machine and newer VS versions.

Comment: @Luishg I’m not very experienced with Microsoft build tools, maybe it is possible

Comment: You can use `<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TextTemplating\Microsoft.TextTemplating.targets" />`

Comment: thanks @StarNamer I will edit my answer

Answer (score 1):

[T4Executer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TimMaes.ttexecuter) might be a solution, it is an VS extension that allows you to trigger the execution of specific T4 files on project build time.