# "Invoke text transformation in the build process" cannot find file Microsoft.VisualStudio.Interop.dl

Tags: c#, visual-studio, templates, t4, visual-studio-2022

I have followed the instructions at [Microsoft: Invoke text transformation in the build process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/modeling/code-generation-in-a-build-process?view=vs-2022) which are also referenced in the StackOverflow answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61390507/t4-templates-not-transformed-during-build).

However, when I try a rebuild, I get a file not found error for a Microsoft dll:

```
An exception was thrown while trying to compile the transformation code. The following Exception was thrown:
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'C:\***Redacted***\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Interop.dll'.
File name: 'C:\***Redacted***\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Interop.dll'
  at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
  at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
  at Roslyn.Utilities.StandardFileSystem.OpenFile(String filePath, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
  at Roslyn.Utilities.CommonCompilerFileSystemExtensions.OpenFileWithNormalizedException(ICommonCompilerFileSystem fileSystem, String filePath, FileMode fileMode, FileAccess fileAccess, FileShare fileShare)
  at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.CompilerBridge.<>c.<.ctor>b__15_0(String x)
  at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator`2.MoveNext()
  at System.Linq.Enumerable.<UnionIterator>d__67`1.MoveNext()
  at System.Linq.Enumerable.<UnionIterator>d__67`1.MoveNext()
  at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
  at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
  at System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableArray.CreateRange[T](IEnumerable`1 items)
  at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Compilation.ValidateReferences[T](IEnumerable`1 references)
  at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CSharpCompilation.WithReferences(IEnumerable`1 references)
  at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.CompilerBridge.PrepareNewCompilation()
  at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.CompilerBridge.Compile()
  at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.TransformationRunner.Compile(String source, String inputFile, IEnumerable`1 references, Boolean debug, SupportedLanguage language, String compilerOptions). Line=0, Column=0
```

The redacted folder is the current project folder, which is presumably the last place searched.

What do I need to do to get this to work?

The current section of my .CSProj file is:

```
   <!-- process *.tt templates on each build  -->
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TransformOnBuild>true</TransformOnBuild>
    <OverwriteReadOnlyOutputFiles>true</OverwriteReadOnlyOutputFiles>
    <TransformOutOfDateOnly>false</TransformOutOfDateOnly>
    <IncludeFolders>$(DevEnvDir)Extensions\Microsoft\Entity Framework Tools\Templates\Includes</IncludeFolders>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TextTemplating\Microsoft.TextTemplating.targets" />
```

---

Update:

I tried this in VS2019 and it worked. So it's a VS2022 issue. As far as I am aware, I have the same components installed.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer for this?
I'm hitting exactly the same issue

Comment: @Maxitone No. But I logged it as a fault with microsoft and, the last time I checked, the issue was marked "Pending release".

Comment: I now have this issue with VS2019 however it works fine with 2022

Comment: This might be the cause: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/migration/breaking-api-list?view=vs-2022

Comment: I have the same issue but can't solve it. Did anyone find out anything?